# Visual Studio: [DebuggerDisplay], shows "not a valid format specifier" when specifying format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, debuggerdisplay

If I specify a (date) format on the `[DebuggerDisplay]`, I see a error CS0726:

> error CS0726: ':d' is not a valid format specifier

For example this code:

```cs
[DebuggerDisplay("{From:d} - {To:d}")
public class DateRange 
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

Shows when debugging in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For specifying the format on the  `[DebuggerDisplay]` you need an expression, e.g. `ToString("d")` - and escape the quotes.

This works:

```cs
[DebuggerDisplay("{From.ToString(\"d\"),nq} - {To.ToString(\"d\"),nq}")
public class DateRange 
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

I also added a `,nq` so we don't render extra quotes.

See [Using Expressions in DebuggerDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2019#using-expressions-in-debuggerdisplay)

Result:

[image]

Note: `,d` won't work for specifying the format - It won't give an error but I also won't change the format

Comment: I prefer to override the ToString(), which is possible in many languages. But, in case I need some different string for debugging purposes, then only I consider using DebuggerDisplay. Not sure if it is not recommended or a bad practice, but I hate to be forced to deal with different unreadable sintaxis, inside the same source code file.